# How to add body class to category and it's child [sub category] Genesis Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, function, genesis

Currently, i just can add body class to pages and the parent category. The subcategory can't inherit the class that i add in body.

- Parent Category

  - SubCategory
  - SubCategory
  - SubCategory

    - SubCategory
    - SubCategory

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function

```
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
  function add_category_to_single($classes) {
     if(is_category()) {

     $term = get_queried_object();

     // Set HERE your subcategories slugs
     $sub_cats_arr = array( 'test1', 'test2', 'test2' );         


     $term_id = $term->term_id; 
     $term_slug = $term->slug; 
     $term_name = $term->name; 
     $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy; 
     $term_parent_id = $term->parent; 

     if ( has_term( $sub_cats_arr, $term_taxonomy ) || in_array($term_slug, $sub_cats_arr) )
        $classes[] = 'services';

    }
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
  }
```

Comment: tried it but it didnt work. i need to add let's say service class to all sub category to that category.

Comment: do you need to add same class for all subcategories?

Comment: same class to all subcategory of that specific parent category.

Comment: actually i tried this awhile ago, and changed the is_product_category to is_category it work. 

My only problem in this, is that it's not dynamic.